# HTML5, difference in data size between blob.slice (start, end) and FileReader() [aka how to work with data in a BLOB]

Tags: javascript, html

[This is](https://github.com/bedna-KU/Slut/blob/master/index_test.html) my first application in HTML5. Application read local file, splits it into chunks and send to server, this works perfectly.

Part of program:

```
    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Read data from chunk
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
      if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        blob_content = evt.target.result; // This problem, chunk != blob_content
      }
    };

    chunk = blob.slice (start, end);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(chunk);
    // readAsBinaryString same

    xhr.open ("post", "upload.php", false);
    xhr.send (blob_content); // This send data about 30% larger
    // xhr.send (chunk); // This send data correctly
```

I need to work with data in a chunk (e.g. encrypt) and do not know how. My fictional function generates data about 30% larger.

Maybe problem with mime type?

Thanks.

Sorry for my excellent English.

Comment: Why do you do `readAsBinaryString` at all? For encryption (which should be done by the connection btw) or any other manipulation, you most likely would want to use `readAsArrayBuffer`.

Comment: Encryption/decryption is only on client side, on server is files encrypted. readAsArrayBuffer return the same result, what wrong? I certainly did not understand anything.

Comment: For one thing, those functions are asynchronous! You will definitely need to put `xhr.send` in the `onloadend` callback; I don't know how elsewise anything could be sent.

Comment: OK, thanks. I go sleep, tomorrow will look at it.

Comment: Still some problems, there is a difference whether I'm reading a text file with diacritics already problems, without diacritics seems OK. Tomorrow I will compare the resulting files via hex editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to  Bergi.

I completely rewritten code to web workers and ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView and synchronously by events.

Main code

(Project at [GitHub](https://github.com/bedna-KU/Slut))

```
  function upload_file () {

    chunk = blob.slice (start, end);
    index++;

    var worker_reader = new Worker('worker_reader.js');
    var worker_uploader = new Worker('worker_uploader.js');

    worker_reader.onmessage = function (event) {
      uload_array={"size": blob.size, "name": blob.name, "content": event.data, "index": index};
      document.getElementById("back_message").innerHTML = "Writing " + blob.name + " " + index;
      worker_reader.terminate();
      return worker_uploader.postMessage(uload_array);
    }

    worker_uploader.onmessage = function (event) {
      if (index < chunks_total) {
        start = end;
        end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
        var percentageDiv = document.getElementById ("percent");
        var progressBar = document.getElementById ("progressBar");

        percentageDiv.innerHTML = "0%";
        progressBar.max = chunks_total;

        progressBar.value = index;

        percentageDiv.innerHTML = Math.round (index/chunks_total * 100) + "%";
        document.getElementById("back_message").innerHTML = "Reading " + blob.name + " " + index;
        worker_uploader.terminate();
        return upload_file ();
      }
      else {
        upload_merge ();
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("back_message").innerHTML = "Reading " + blob.name + " " + index;
    worker_reader.postMessage(chunk);
  }
```

Bergi again thanks.

EDIT// Add terminate worker and respawn because Firefox have bug in Garbage Collector. Chromium without this work properly. (With file over 200GB)